# Is there a way to populate a 2d array from time series data - Python

Tags: python, plotly

Apologies for the poor formatting, on mobile.

I have a large time-series dataset that has 4 columns.

`Time   A   B   C`

I want to populate a new 2d array from this data, where;

The number of rows is given by the number of unique values for A (x-axis).

The number of columns is given by the number of unique values for B (y-axis).

Assuming ascending order for the column and row values, the values in each 'cell' should be the corresponding values for C (z-axis).

Where no corresponding value exists, the 'cell' should be `None`

Where more than one corresponding value exists, the cell should contain the average value.

For context, I want to use this data to plot a contour chart using Plotly but need to minimise the amount of interpolation that's inherent to these chart types, None valuea would show blank. I understand that I'll need to also define a corresponding 2d array for both A (x-axis) & C (y-axis).

Is there a python function to allow this to be done easily without manually stating the number of unique values?

**UPDATE - Resolved**

I ended up using pivot_table and aggfunc to set what happens to the duplicates, like this;

```
pivot_table = pd.pivot_table(df, values='C', index='B', columns='A', aggfunc=np.mean)

z_values = pivot_table.values
x_values = pivot_table.columns.values
y_values = pivot_table.index.values

self.fig.add_trace(go.Contour(x=x_values, y=y_values, z=z_values, connectgaps=False))
```

Comment: No, but this is pretty easy to do with a loop.  Find the range of A, find the range of B, construct an empty matrix, fill it in.  What have you tried so far?

Comment: Thanks! I tried pivot but duplicates got in the way!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Indeed, I think looping through the dataframe would be the easiest. Pivot doesn't work with duplicates...

Something like this (I didn't test the exact syntax):

```
new_df = pd.DataFrame(index=df.A.unique())
for r in df.A.unique():
    for c in df.B.unique():
        result_c = df[df.A==r & df.B==c]['C'].mean()
        new_df.at[r,c] = result_c
```

Comment: Thank you! I think this would work well but I ended up finding a nice way to use Pivot for this problem, you can set aggfunc to decide what happens to the duplicates! I will update my question with the solution.